# Windows Error 'Procedure number is out of range'

Tags: windows, dns

When I try to add a computer name to a domain or when changing the computer name, I see error

**Computer Name\Domain changes (error dialog box title as seen)

The following error occured validating the name 'XXXXX' (where XXXXX is my computer name)

'Procedure number is out of range'. **

Help me to resolve this issue. I don't know what it means and googling around didn't help much.

OS is 'Windows Embedded Standard SP 1 2010' 32 bit

I tried googling and change some registry but those didn't help.

I must be able to change my computer name as well as add my computer to a domain without issues.